# Getting migration Errors

Tags: python, django-models, django-migrations

I am getting migration errors.i tried deleting my previous migrations.error tells it's failed to write/create migration files errors are give below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
 execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
 File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages         /django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
 File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
  self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
 self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
 File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
  output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
  res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 184, in handle
  self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 222, in  write_migration_files
   migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 151, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
   File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 110, in serialize
_write(arg_name, arg_value)
 File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 62, in _write
arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
 File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 279, in serialize
  return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 37, in serialize
  item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 197, in serialize
  return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 85, in serialize_deconstructed
arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
File "/home/clifton/Documents/all_venvs/unica/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 149, in serialize
raise ValueError("Cannot serialize function %r: No module" % self.value)
 ValueError: Cannot serialize function <built-in method time of datetime.datetime object at 0x7f1ec51abb40>: No module
```

Answer (score 1):

You had this issue with using time in the custom field definition.

It is than hard to spot as it is not listed in traceback and the error is not raised on the particular model which uses such custom field.

But, try to add `auto_now_add=True` in the Time field in your model